# "What sport is this medal table?" is back

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, geography, history

[On exactly the same spirit as "What sport is this medal table"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/114899/51928)

---

**Can you find the values of the question marks in this medal table?**

Three questions for you:

1. Is it related to the Olympic Games?
2. Two medal numbers are missing, what are they?
3. What is the missing country that has smashed the table? What about the two other nations?

[image]

**Markdown Transcription**

| Total | Gold | Silver | Bronze |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 18 | 4 | ? |  |
| NOR | 7 | ? | 1 | Norway |
| URS | 5 | 2 | 0 | Soviet Union |
| FIN | 3 | 2 | 1 | Finland |
| GDR | 3 | 1 | 0 | East Germany |
| GER | 2 | 2 | 1 | Germany |
| NOD | 2 | 1 | 0 | Netherland |
| SWE | 1 | 4 | 0 | Sweden |
| AUS | 1 | 1 | 0 | Australia |
|  | 1 | 0 | 0 |  |
|  | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |
| GBR | 0 | 1 | 0 | Great Britain |
| FRA | 0 | 0 | 1 | France |

#### Hint 1. 21st February 2022

> Yes it is Olympic Games related!

#### Hint 2. 24th February 2022

> USA is the top nation in the table. The two other missing countries never ever won any medal in the winter Olympics. They had 37 athletes combined participating in winter Olympics and, therefore, none of them won any medal.

Comment: With regards to Hint 2: rot13(Vf gur 37 n pbzovarq ahzore bs nguyrgrf be qvq obgu pbhagevrf unir 37 rnpu)?

Comment: @xyldke, I edited my hint to answer you :)

Comment: Unfortunately the first part of the second hint didn't help me that much, as I expected it. All the ideas I have for what the catch is don't seem to work...

Comment: Is this connected to DOPING and/or DISQUALIFICATIONS ?